# What are workouts or stretches to increase flexibility for the splits?

Tags: stretching, flexibility

What kind of workout or stretches can I do to increase my range of motion? I want to be able to do a split (I am quite close).

What kind of stretch should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to stretch your hip-flexors, hamstrings and quadriceps.

There are a multitude of resources on how to stretch these areas on sites such as Youtube. [Here is a video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pVq9nL_tLbo) I found that includes a bunch of good stretches.

You can also do fire-hydrants (and variations), scorpions and iron crosses.